# Reading a single UTF8 character from stream in C#

Tags: c#, utf-8, stream

I am looking to read the next UTF8 character from a Stream or BinaryReader. Things that don't work:

BinaryReader::ReadChar -- this will throw on a 3 or 4 byte character. Since it returns a two byte structure, it has no choice.

BinaryReader::ReadChars -- this will throw if you ask it to read 1 character and it encounters a 3 or 4 byte character. Will read multiple characters if you ask it to read more than 1 character.

StreamReader::Read -- this needs to know how many bytes to read, but the number of bytes in a UTF8 character is variable.

The code I have that seems to work:

```
    private char[] ReadUTF8Char(Stream s)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
        var enc = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);
        if (1 != s.Read(bytes, 0, 1))
            return null;
        if (bytes[0] <= 0x7F) //Single byte character
        {
            return enc.GetChars(bytes, 0, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            var remainingBytes =
                ((bytes[0] & 240) == 240) ? 3 : (
                ((bytes[0] & 224) == 224) ? 2 : (
                ((bytes[0] & 192) == 192) ? 1 : -1
            ));
            if (remainingBytes == -1)
                return null;
            s.Read(bytes, 1, remainingBytes);
            return enc.GetChars(bytes, 0, remainingBytes + 1);
        }
    }
```

Obviously, this is a bit of a mess, and somewhat specific to UTF8. Is there a more elegant, less custom, easier-to-read solution to this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671826/how-do-you-read-utf-8-characters-from-an-infinite-byte-stream-c-sharp

Comment: Question may be a duplicate, but that answer doesn't work. Specifically, it doesn't handle surrogate pairs. I tried modifying it to use a 2-element char buffer, but that just caused a different issue.

Other than the surrogate pairs, though, it works fine.

Comment: Cool, I wasn't 100% sure if it was the same thing but I thought it might have some useful information in it.

Comment: It was a good find -- my searching hadn't turned it up. Sadly, the question of "is there something that works, but is less ugly than my current solution" stands.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old but here is another solution. It is not as good in performance as the OPs solution (which I also prefer), but it only uses builtin-utf8-functionality without knowing about the utf8-encoding internals.

```
private static char ReadUTF8Char(Stream s)
{
    if (s.Position >= s.Length)
        throw new Exception("Error: Read beyond EOF");

    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(s, Encoding.Unicode, true))
    {
        int numRead = Math.Min(4, (int)(s.Length - s.Position));
        byte[] bytes = reader.ReadBytes(numRead);
        char[] chars = Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(bytes);

        if (chars.Length == 0)
            throw new Exception("Error: Invalid UTF8 char");

        int charLen = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(new char[] { chars[0] });

        s.Position += (charLen - numRead);

        return chars[0];
    }
}
```

The encoding passed to the constructor of `BinaryReader` doesn't matter. I had to use this version of the constructor to leave the stream open. If you already have a binary reader you can just use this:

```
private static char ReadUTF8Char(BinaryReader reader)
{
    var s = reader.BaseStream;

    if (s.Position >= s.Length)
        throw new Exception("Error: Read beyond EOF");

    int numRead = Math.Min(4, (int)(s.Length - s.Position));
    byte[] bytes = reader.ReadBytes(numRead);
    char[] chars = Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(bytes);

    if (chars.Length == 0)
        throw new Exception("Error: Invalid UTF8 char");

    int charLen = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(new char[] { chars[0] });

    s.Position += (charLen - numRead);

    return chars[0];
}
```